# Retrieve geojson property and make layer visible but only based on some values of properties (OL3)

Tags: openlayers, geojson, heat-map, zoom

Please take a look at code: https://plnkr.co/edit/wF8VZnnLtRLHPkfrKGu5?p=preview
(OpenLayers v.3.8.2)

I would like to retrieve GeoJSON property "zoom".
I guess it would be something like this but dont know where to put it in a code:

```
var zoom = function(feature){
    var zoomGeojson = feature.get("zoom");
    console.log(zoomGeojson);
}
```

And then I would like to compare zoom level of the map to the GeoJSON property "zoom". If they would match, I would like to visualize only that geojson data. (for example: mapzoomlevel = 5, if mapzoomlevel = geojsonpropertyzoom visualize only data from geojson that contains property "zoom"=5)

#### **Edit**

Based on @Hicham Zouarhi answer.

I ran into two problems.

1.Code below throws me an error:

```
var tmpLayer= new ol.layer.Vector();
map.addLayer(tmpLayer);

source.forEachFeature(function(feature){
    var mapzoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    var geojsonzoom = feature.get("zoom");
    console.log('MapZoom ' + mapzoom);
    console.log('GeoJSONZoom ' + geojsonzoom); 
    if(geojsonzoom == mapzoom){
        console.log('GeoJSON zoom property and map zoom are equal!'); 
        tmpLayer.getSource().addFeatures(feature); // error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addFeatures' of null(…) 
    } else {
        console.log('Not equal!'); 
    }
});
```

2. Without that error it runs smoothly in a console, however it does not run in my code at all. I guess I am missing something or the order is not right.

I have reorganized code by breaking it into a smaller pieces: https://plnkr.co/edit/DeaVFGBK11jKCT3yHAVd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I propose ( I still think there may be a cleaner way to do it, so if you find any please share ):

1. loop through all the features of you GeoJSON data
2. get the features that do have the zoom value equal to `yourMap.getView().getZoom()`
3. add the features to a temporary vector layer and display it while setting the original one visibility to false.

the code to do this should look like this :

```
var tmpLayer= new ol.layer.Vector({ source: new ol.source.Vector()});
yourMap.addLayer(tmpLayer);
//----- this goes before 
// this loop goes inside moveend event
tmplLayergetSource()clear(); // we clear the source to avoid duplicates
yourSource.forEachFeature(function(feature){
    if(feature.get("zoom")==yourMap.getView().getZoom()){
         tmpLayer.getSource().addFeature(feature);
    }
});
if(tmpLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length>0){
     tmpLayer.setVisible(true);
     yourVectorLayer.setVisible(false);
}
```

the loop through the vector source features should be inside the `map.on('moveend',...);` this way it will listen to any change on the zoom level of the map

Comment: Hi! I appriciate you answer! Thought I would be doing something like that, but as I am a beginner in OL3, as well in a JS, I ran into some problems. Please take a look at EDIT part I ve provided in the main question.

Comment: @vayacondios2015 I've edited the answer, added a source to the temporary layer

Comment: Thanks! Wouldnt thought that would be it in a million of years. It doesnt throw me an error now if I run code over a console and it creates vector file (which I still need to check). However, it does not write any kind of outcome to console and it doesnt create new vector layer if I write code in a script.  Where do I need to place code in a script?

Comment: @vayacondios2015 the code should go inside `map.on('moveend', ...);` I tried it in your plunker and it worked. sorry for the delay of the reply

Comment: thank you for helping me out! I really appriciate it! it wasnt working in the beginning because I had to change tmpLayer.getSource().length>0 to tmpLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length>0, but as far I can see, its working properly now! I have edited your code above and accepted it as agood answer! thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome :) thanks for pointing the missing `getFeatures()`